# [android]spinner onItemSelected and visibility

Tags: android, spinner, visibility

I try to make editText and TextView visibility triggered by select item on spinner. I use the code below but it does not work. The item should be gone at first time and when i select item on the spinner editText and TextView will show up. What happen is The editText and TextView show up at the first time and when i select another item the editText and TextView won't gone.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SP_KMA);
    Spiner_KMA.setAdapter(adapter2);

    Spiner_KMA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String select = arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("ganti meter")){
                txt_ganti_meter.setVisibility(1);
                et_id_ganti_meter.setVisibility(1);
            }else{
                txt_ganti_meter.setVisibility(2);
                et_id_ganti_meter.setVisibility(2);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently u are passing wrong constant values to `setVisibility` for making a View  `INVISIBLE` or  `VISIBLE` :

as in [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) class :

> Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002) :The view is not important for accessibility.

and

> Constant Value: 1 (0x00000002) :The view is important for accessibility.

u will pass `0` and `4` to make View Visible or InVisible

**For VISIBLE :**  `setVisibility(0)` or `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

**For INVISIBLE :**  `setVisibility(4)` or `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

**For GONE :**  `setVisibility(8)` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility like this

```
txt_ganti_meter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

txt_ganti_meter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this
txt_ganti_meter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or
txt_ganti_meter.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE) as required